# ¿No puedo abrir una imagen en python con openCV y en pycharm?

Tags: python, opencv, python-3.7, pycharm

Estoy intentado abrir una imagen en `python` pero no lo consigo hacer, este es el código que estoy usando:

```py
    import cv2

    imagen = cv2.imread('C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\VI\IMAGENES\Nueva carpeta',1)
    cv2.imshow("Prueba de imagen",imagen)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! ¿Que error te sale?

Answer (score 0):

```
imagen = cv2.imread('C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\VI\IMAGENES\Nueva carpeta',1)
```

En la función `cv2.imread` no le estas dando la dirección de una imagen **(ej: picture.jpg)**, sino de una carpeta.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que además de lo que te ha respondido Alexmaister la ruta no te la debe estar reconociendo bien ya que `\` es el caracter de escape. Tienes varias opciones:

```
# Con la 'r' le dices que no procese la cadena, que la lea tal cual.
imagen = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\TOSHIBA\Desktop\VI\IMAGENES\Nueva carpeta\imagen.jpg',1)

# Con \ escapas el siguiente caracter, en este caso \
imagen = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\TOSHIBA\\Desktop\\VI\\IMAGENES\\Nueva carpeta\\imagen.jpg',1)

# Puedes escribir las rutas con /
imagen = cv2.imread('C:/Users/TOSHIBA/Desktop/VI/IMAGENES/Nueva carpeta/imagen.jpg',1)
```

Por último, si tienes la imagen en la misma ruta que tu archivo .py, no necesitarías escribir la ruta entera, puedes ponerlo solo así:

```
imagen = cv2.imread('imagen.jpg',1)
```